# Unexpected Constructor called in class

Tags: c++

There are some Classes:  Array, NumericArray. Array is a template class, and NumericArray is a class inherited from Array designed to take int, double, etc.

Part of Header of NumericArray:

```
template <class T = int> 
class NumericArray : public Array<T>{
    private:
        T* m_data;
        int size;

    public:

        NumericArray<T> operator * (T factor)const;

};
```

here are constructors and some functions of NumericArray:

```
template <class T>
NumericArray<T>::NumericArray(){
    m_data = new T[10];
    size = 10;
}

template <class T>
NumericArray<T>::NumericArray(int n){
    m_data = new T[n];
    size = n;
}

template <class T>
NumericArray<T>::NumericArray(const NumericArray<T>& s_data){
    m_data = new T[s_data.size];
    // assign elements in the source array
    for (int i = 0;i<=(s_data.Size()-1 ); i++){
        m_data[i] = s_data.m_data[i];
    }
    size = s_data.Size();
}

/*  Destructor  */
template <class T>
NumericArray<T>::~NumericArray(){
    delete [] m_data;
}

template <class T>
NumericArray<T> NumericArray<T>::operator * (T factor)const{
    NumericArray<T> temp(size);
    for (int i = 0; i<size;i++){
        temp.m_data[i] = (*this)[i] *factor;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

And when I call it in the main(), something weird happens. For example:

```
NumericArray<int> intArray1(10);
NumericArray<int> intArray2;
for(int i =0; i<10;i++){
    intArray1[i] = i;
    intArray2[i] = i;
}
```

The 2 arrays do contain numbers 0-9, but if I call
    NumericArray intArray4 = intArray1*2;

intArray4 consists of zero(0)s. It seems that the default constructor is called in the function and passed to Array4. And after the operator, Array1 and Array2 are still numbers 0-9

Below are the related code of Array

template  class Array{

```
private:
    T* m_data;
    int size;

public:
    Array();    // constructor
    Array(int n);   // constructor
    Array(const Array<T>& s_data);  //Copy Constructor

    virtual ~Array();   // destructor

    void SetElement(int i, const T& source);
    T& GetElement(int i)const;
    int Size() const;
    int DefaultSize()const;
    void DefaultSize(int n);

    // Operator overloading
    Array<T>& operator = (const Array<T>& source) ;
    T& operator [](int i);
    const T& operator [] (int i) const;
};



template <class T>
Array<T>::Array(){
    //  default constructor
    m_data = new T[defaultSize];    // initialize T*
    size = defaultSize;             // initialize integer
}

template <class T>
Array<T>::Array(int n){
    // Constructor with arguments
    m_data = new T[n];
    size = n;
}

template <class T>
Array<T>::Array(const Array<T>& s_data){
    // Copy constructor
    m_data = new T[s_data.Size()];
    // assign elements in the source array
    for (int i = 0;i<=(s_data.Size()-1 ); i++){
        m_data[i] = T( s_data.m_data[i]);
    }
    size = s_data.Size();
    defaultSize = s_data.Size();
}

template <class T>
T& Array<T>::operator [](int i) {
    if (i > size|| i<0){
        OutOfBoundsException a;
        throw a;
    }
    return m_data[i];   
}
```

Not sure if provided enough information. Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: in `NumericArray`, why do you both inherit an `m_data` member from `Array`, and add one in this derived class. also why are you not using `std::vector`. also, for numeric arrays, check out `std::valarray`

Comment: And similar problems happen in other situations where I tried to call another Class, Point, in a PointArray class. The "Points" passed to the function call are turn to _Point(0,0)_ s, which is what default constructor sets. So my guess is somehow the default constructor is used instead of use the "real" objects.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It seems that the 2 members are not inherited (is it because of generic inheritance?) so I need to add them in the derived class, or compiler says m_data is not declared.

Comment: well your interpretation of things is incorrect. there are 2 obstacles to accessing the base class' data members in the derived class. one is that these are class templates, not concrete classes, so for unqualified access you need to inform the compiler that the members exist in the base class, e.g. via `using`. secondly, you have declared them `private`.  i suggest that you try some simpler exercise before tackling this one.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yes they are private and I did tried 20+ exercises on class, but it somehow happens and I need to tackle it. (Yes it's the first template Class I've used)

Comment: Suppress data members in NumericArray, make data members in Array protected (just for debugging), then access them in NumericArray member function with this->m_data and this->size, and it will work

Comment: @BérengerBerthoul I tried but the "protected" way does not work.

Comment: @BérengerBerthoul things do not change. If I comment out the m_data  in the derived class, compiler will say m_data is not declared in the scope.

Comment: Did you used this->m_data and this->size instead of m_data and size in all your implementations of NumericArray functions ?

Comment: @BérengerBerthoul Yes I did ... I just tried to debug using cout and it seems that the temp variable in the function has non-zero value , however when get out of the function, it became an all-zero array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem: both `NumericArray` and `Array` have

```
T* m_data;
int size;
```

The function `Array::operator[]` is called from `Array` which uses `Array::m_data`, however the `NumericArray::operator*` sets `NumericAray::m_data`.  It probably is working as you would expect, but you are reading from the wrong pointer.

Remove the members from `NumericArray` and make the members `protected` instead of `private` in `Array`.  The second part is optional if the implementation is changed a little bit.

Comment: My friend told me the same way but I tried and the protected way does not work. I still need to declare the two member data in the derived class.

Comment: 'does not work" in what way?  Fails to compile, or still fails to run correctly?

Comment: Reading comments in the OP, I suspect the problem is that it didn't compile.  Obviously you have to fix those errors too...  Try putting `using Array<T>::m_data;` in `NumericArray` for starters, but some other things will obviously have to change as well to fix the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access base class data members when the base is a (dependent) class template, is a `using` declaration like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template< class Item >
class Base
{
protected:
    Item    item_;

    Base( Item const& v ): item_( v ) {}
};

template< class Item >
class Derived
    : public Base< Item >
{
protected:
    using Base<Item>::item_;

public:
    auto value() const -> Item { return item_; }
    Derived( Item const& v ): Base<Item>( v ) {}
};

auto main() -> int
{
    Derived<int> const x( 42 );
    cout << x.value() << endl;
}
```

Alternatively you can qualify the access, e.g. `this->item_` or `Base<Item>::item_`.

That said, it’s usually not a good idea to let derived classes access base class data members directly.

Comment: What is this craziness: `auto main() -> int`?  I know what it means with C++11 stuff, but that seems unnecessarily unorthodox.

Comment: do you have any argument for the orthodox mixing of two syntaxes, outside of legacy code?

Comment: It's simply not necessary to venture away from the canonical `main` declaration in this case.  It would be like writing while-loops in place of every for-loop: it does the same thing, it's perfectly readable, and yet I'll bet SO users will slap you on the wrists if they see while-loop code doing things that are canonically expressed in for-loops.  Perhaps you just want to practice the new C++11 candies, but this new syntax was not meant to replace the original way to declare non-template functions.

Comment: @Aggieboy: thank you. summing up, you see an advantage in *conforming* to group perception, and indeed that's a valid point of view. i have actively and consistently failed to conform to group perception in my life, and have therefore been slapped on the wrists, as you put it, so many times that it has in turn affected some key people's perception of me, namely those non-technical very socially attuned individuals known as HR (no, not Hells Rangers). and that may be a good guiding principle for you. me, due to my situation i can choose that which is meaningful technically and objectively.